# How to narrow a list of unions?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, union-types, narrowing

I have a variable of type `list[A | B]` that could hold a mixed list (like `[A(), B(), A()]`).

If I later reach some corner case and I want to make sure all elements are actually of type `A`, I can `assert isinstance` inside a `for`-loop:

```py
def f(mylist: list[A | B]):
    ...
    ...
    for el in mylist:
        assert isinstance(el, A)
    # Now, I'm sure that mylist is actually `list[A]`
    # How do I tell that to the type checker?
```

After the `for`-loop, if I `reveal_type(mylist)` it still says `list[A|B]`. I also tried `assert all(isinstance(el, A) for el in mylist)` instead of the explicit loop, but `mypy` still isn't able to narrow it. Is this possible? Or do I have to use `cast` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or do I have to use cast here?

Using Python 3.10 the only alternative to using `cast` that can narrow a list would be using a [TypeGuard](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeGuard), this code:

```py
from typing import TypeGuard


def is_str_list(val: list[int | str]) -> TypeGuard[list[str]]:
    """Determines whether all objects in the list are strings"""
    return all(isinstance(x, str) for x in val)


def is_int_list(val: list[int | str]) -> TypeGuard[list[int]]:
    """Determines whether all objects in the list are ints"""
    return all(isinstance(x, int) for x in val)


def f(mylist: list[int | str]):

    if is_str_list(mylist):
        reveal_type(mylist)

    elif is_int_list(mylist):
        reveal_type(mylist)

    reveal_type(mylist)
```

narrows the type of the list without using `cast`:

```
narrow_collection.py:17: note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[builtins.str]"
narrow_collection.py:21: note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[builtins.int]"
narrow_collection.py:24: note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[Union[builtins.int, builtins.str]]"
```